# jQuery doesn't process result

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring

In my script i send data to check if username exists in database, but user is created anyway. I've checked that controller works fine. Am I processing the result in a correct way?

My script

```
 $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 600,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Create an account": function() {
                    var bValid = true;
                    allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );                                               
                    var values = $("form").serialize();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/checkLogin",
                        data: values,
                        success: function(result) {
                            bValid = result == 'true';}})
                    if ( bValid ) {
                        var values = $("form").serialize();
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addUser",
                            data: values
                        })
                        $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
                                "<td>" + login.val() + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + fname.val() + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + lname.val() + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + bday.val() + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + role.val() + "</td>" +
                                "<td>"+ "<a href=\"/edit/" + login.val() + "\">Edit   </a>"
                                + "<a href=\"/delete/" + login.val() + ".json\">Delete</a></td>" +
                                "</tr>" );
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            close: function() {
                allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
            }
        });
        $( "#create-user" )
                .button()
                .click(function() {
                    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
                });
    });
```

Here's my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/checkLogin", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public boolean check(@RequestParam("login") String login) {
    return (userService.findByLogin(login) == null);
}
```

Here's my html

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">    
<form:form >
    <fieldset>
        <label for="login">Login</label>
        <input type="text" name="login" id="login" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />            
    </fieldset>
</form:form>
</div>
<button id="create-user">Add user</button>
```

Comment: Have you tried `if (result=="false"){` ...?? Guess the controller returns "false" and not false (real boolean) ..

Comment: Better to test `if (result=='true')` (positive match) for exactly this reason.

Comment: None of it worked. User is created anyway.

Comment: Can we see more context for your javascript block? How is that called?

Comment: I've updated my post: added more context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the relevant parts of the function for the "create user" button:

```
var bValid = true;
//...
$.ajax({
    //...
    success: function (result) {
        bValid = result == 'true';
    }
})
if (bValid) {
    //create user
}
```

`$.ajax` is async. That means that as soon as the ajax request is fired (and before the reponse is returned), execution continues on to the `if (bValid)` check. Since you defined that as true above, the block executes and the user is created.

I see two options:

1. Move the entire `if (bValid)` block into the first ajax callback.
2. Remove the "username exists" ajax check, and do that validation on the server during the user creation process (which you should be doing anyway). That way, you only need one ajax call, and users can't circumvent the validation.

Comment: About second statement: I'm sending username to Spring controller and return true or false if username already exists. Is it server-side check?

Comment: It is, but initiated via javascript, and independent of the user creation function. If I wanted to, I could debug the javascript, and manually change the value of `bValid` to true, bypassing your validation. The username check also needs to occur during the user creation function. And given the workflow, it seems that having separate checks is unnecessary.

Comment: Could you please assist me, what will be the correct way to do such check. I can't figure out how do display an error if user exists, or should i start new question for this one?